# Flutter Failed to extract native libraries, res=-18

Tags: android, flutter, dart, ads

the Problem is that when I try to run my Flutter app on a android emulator I get this error message after the `Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...`   was successful

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /Users/Uesrname/Desktop/projectFolder/ProjectName/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk: Failure
[INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR: Failed to extract native libraries,res=-18]
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 arm64.
```

searched all over the internet for a selution but all I found where errors that looked seemlier but are not the same

Answer (score 0):

the simple solution to this issue was to delete my old `ADV` and download a new device with the latest `system image`

in my case it was `API 34`

[image]